# Cuts the header of a web page when viewing through a smartphone browser (ASP.net Core MVC 3.1)

Tags: html, css, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

Created a web application on the ASP.net Core MVC 3.1 stack. There are web pages that are cropped (in the header and to the table) when viewed from a mobile phone at a resolution of 360 by 740. When viewed from a tablet or PC, everything is fine. I tried to change both the _Layout file and the View file. But no have positive effect.

[It's ok here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxI3V.png)

[When viewing from a mobile cut in "Head" and below:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwTfW.png)

**_Layout.cshtml:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>   
   
    <link rel="stylesheet" asp-href-include="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/*.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/fontawesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/a076d05399.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-collapse w3-card w3-animate-left w3-indigo" style="width:200px;" id="mySidebar">
        <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-large w3-hide-large w3-hover-white" onclick="w3_close()">&times;</button>

        <center><h1>HOMIE</h1></center>
        <hr>

        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-white">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-home"></i>&nbsp; Домой
        </a>

        <button class="w3-button w3-block w3-left-align w3-hover-white" onclick="myAccSeriesFunc()">
            <i class="fa fa-film fa-fw fa-lg"></i>&nbsp; Сериалы <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div id="seriesAcc" class="w3-hide w3-light-gray w3-card">
            <a asp-area="Series" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-white">
                <i class="fa fa-video fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Просмотр
            </a>

            <a asp-area="Series" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="ArchMovies" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-white">
                <i class="fa fa-fast-backward fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Архив
            </a>
        </div>

        <a asp-area="Cigars" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-white">
            <i class="fas fa-joint fa-lg"></i>&nbsp; Сигары
        </a>        

        <a method="post" asp-area="Identity" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-white"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt fa-lg"></i>&nbsp; Выход</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="w3-main" style="margin-left:200px">

        <div class="w3-indigo">
            <button class="w3-button w3-xlarge w3-hide-large" onclick="w3_open()">&#9776;</button>
            <div class="w3-container w3-indigo">
                <h1>@ViewBag.HeaderTitle</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p></p>

        <div class="w3-container">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>

        <script>    

            function myAccSeriesFunc() {
                var x = document.getElementById("seriesAcc");
                if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
                x.className += " w3-show";
                x.previousElementSibling.className += " w3-white";
                } else {
                x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
                x.previousElementSibling.className =
                    x.previousElementSibling.className.replace(" w3-white", "");
                }                
            }

            function myAccAdminFunc() {
                var y = document.getElementById("adminAcc");
                if (y.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
                y.className += " w3-show";
                y.previousElementSibling.className += " w3-white";
                } else {
                y.className = y.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
                y.previousElementSibling.className =
                    y.previousElementSibling.className.replace(" w3-white", "");
                }
            }

            function w3_open() {
                document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "block";

            }

            function w3_close() {
                document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "none";
            }
        </script>
    </div>

   

</body>
</html>
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```html
@using Homie.Models
@model IndexViewModel

@addTagHelper *, Homie

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Список выкуренных сигар";
    ViewBag.HeaderTitle = "Сигары - - - - [ История ]";
}

<style>
    .table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td,
    .table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th {
        background-color: sandybrown;
    }    
</style>

<a asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Home" asp-area="Cigars"
   class="btn btn-primary"
   role="button">Добавить</a>
<p></p>

<form method="get">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <label>Название: </label>
        <input name="name" value="@Model.FilterViewModel.SelectedName" class="form-control" />

        <label>Формат: </label>        
        <select name="format" asp-items="Model.FilterViewModel.Formats" class="form-control"></select>        

        <input type="submit" value="Фильтр" class="btn btn-outline-dark" />
    </div>
</form>
<p></p>

<div>
    <label>Количество сигар: @Model.PageViewModel.CountPages</label>
</div>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <a asp-action="Index"
               asp-route-sortOrder="@(Model.SortViewModel.NameSort)"
               asp-route-name="@(Model.FilterViewModel.SelectedName)"
               asp-route-format="@(Model.FilterViewModel.SelectedFormat)">Название</a>
        </th>
        <th>Страна</th>
        <th>Цена</th>
        <th>Рейтинг</th>
        <th>
            <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@(Model.SortViewModel.FormatSort)"
               asp-route-name="@(Model.FilterViewModel.SelectedName)"
               asp-route-format="@(Model.FilterViewModel.SelectedFormat)">Формат</a>
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var p in Model.Cigars)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@p.Name</td>
            <td>@p.Country</td>
            <td>@p.Price</td>
            <td>@p.Rating</td>
            <td>@p.Shape</td>
            <td>

                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="Home" asp-route-id="@p.Id" class="btn btn-success"
                   role="button">Изменить</a>
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-controller="Home" asp-route-id="@p.Id" class="btn btn-danger"
                   role="button">Удалить</a>
            </td>
        </tr>

    }
</table>
<p></p>
<page-link page-model="Model.PageViewModel" page-action="Index"
           page-url-name="@(Model.FilterViewModel.SelectedName)"
           page-url-company="@(Model.FilterViewModel.SelectedFormat)"
           page-url-sortorder="@(Model.SortViewModel.Current)"></page-link>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nature of `<table>` is that they are fixed-width. You need to make your table have a scroll bar when it exceeds the parent width, or find some way to collapse the columns on mobile (DataTables.js has some good tools for this out of the box). Below is the example of making the table scroll:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lv3sw20g/6/

Comment: That is, if I make a scroll bar on the table, will the upper borders be stretched?
I just do not really understand. After all, the table is correctly displayed in full width. 
The problem isn't at the top?

Comment: Nope. The table is pushing the width of the entire page from what I can tell.

Comment: Ok. I'll make scroll bar and I hope this fixes the problem. Thanks!!